# Change nodejs route with params at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I  need to change a route params at runtime in nodejs.

In my code I set a route using:

```
const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page,sessionId)
app.use('/teste' + sessionId, troutes)
```

But, in runtime, sometimes the "page" object param is recreated and it becomes invalid. But the "sessionId" param is the same, no changes.
Then I create a new "page"  and need remake the route, because the old route has a invalid page.
if I use:

```
let page={newpage};
const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page,sessionId);
```

My urls don´t work because the route use the old invalid "page" param object.

How could I delete or change the old route and use the new route with the new "page" object?

//server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const port = 3001
const host = 'http://localhost'
const callbackUrl = `${host}:${port}`;

let page={page};
let sessionId='sessionId';
const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page,sessionId)
app.use('/teste' + sessionId, troutes)
....
});
```

//routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = function (page,sessionId) {
        router.get('/'+sessionId+'/getMyNumber', async (req, res) => {
            const cc = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return getMyNumber();
            });
            console.log(cc);
            res.send({ "data": cc });
        });

        return router;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since you called `require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page,sessionId)` method only once in file, it loads only once. so passed parameters/initializations within function executed only once.

the router which is initialized and returned is used for further request processing.So new request will only trigger method of router.

if you want page to be dynamic, it would work if you move page inside router, instead of passing it from wrapper function as below.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
module.exports = function (sessionId) {
        router.get('/'+sessionId+'/getMyNumber', async (req, res) => {
             let page = {newPage}
            const cc = await page.evaluate(() => {
                return getMyNumber();
            });
            console.log(cc);
            res.send({ "data": cc });
        });

        return router;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I can´t use the page inside the module, because the page is a chrome page created with puppeteer. When the chrome page crash, I recreate  the page and I pass the new page to router module. Then, the page is allways created outside from router module. I have some js functions loaded into chrome page, and to access that functions I need pass to router the correct page. I need locate the old route, delete it or update it to use with the new page.

Comment: I dont  call the module only one time, I call  require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page,sessionId) allways I have a new page. Because, my urls only will be valid if I access using the new page.

Comment: When I have a new page I use: const troutes = require('./src/routes/testroutes')(page,sessionId)
app.use('/teste' + sessionId, troutes), again. But, in Router, I can see the page is showing the attribute closed, when I call my urls. This indicates the router is using the old page.